# How can I generate a random number every 24 hours in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate the word of the day from a list of words that are stored in a database. How can I generate a random number every 24 hours so that I can use it as an id to get the words from the database? Thank you!

Comment: Is this going to be implemented on client or server-side?

Comment: why do you want to do this in Javascript?

Comment: i wok with PhoneGap and it is limited to CSS, HTML and JavaScript

Comment: I don't see why he can't do it in JS but client-side JS doesn't seem like a good solution. Is the database on the device or on a server somewhere?

Comment: JavaScritp clientside solution means every user will have a different random number. The server would need to generate the random number.

Comment: okay, PhoneGap user, just google out two things: 1. how to generate random number in javascript. 2. how to use setInterval method in javascript. you shd be done

Comment: Don't know JS, but can't you call `Randomise` using the Date as a seed (assuming JS stores this as number of days from a given date) then calling Random(x)? This will have the effect that the client will own divide time into their own 24 hour blocks, but the result from a user-perspective should be similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange stuff to do in client-side JavaScript, but here it goes:

## Random Number Generator

```
// Returns a random integer between min and max
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

## Generate New Number Every 24 Hours

```
var rand = getRandom();

var handle = setInterval(function () {
    rand = getRandom(LOWER_BOUND, UPPER_BOUND);
    // console.log("new random number is: " + rand);
}, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

## Notes

- See [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) and [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)for details on the generator.
- See [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) for details on setting up the timer, and also [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval) if you need to cancel the repeat event using the `handle` variable.
- Set `LOWER_BOUND` and `UPPER_BOUND` based on your needs (here, likely to be defined by the number of items in your table).
- Adapt timer as needed.
- You may want to consider a stronger random number generator than this, there are plenty of more advanced (but more complex) alternatives.

Comment: this will get a new random number on page load though. perhaps you could store an existing number in a cookie for 24 hrs

Comment: @andrew: I'm merely answering what is asked, I don't speculate on what the needs are. You could also use the `localStorage` to retrive the current status, and a herd of other possibilities. That works for what the OP asked.